# Access Windows XP files from Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, windows-xp

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04, dual boot with Windows XP, and I would now like to access my Windows XP files from Ubuntu. How do I do so?

My Ubuntu desktop menu does not have 'Applications', 'Places', or 'System', as seen on one or two websites that I've investigated.

I've installed 'gparted' and managed to open the terminal window, type sudo -s,..., /mnt/windows
I cannot find a folder called 'windows'.

This is day 2 of my entire Ubuntu experience, so I've a lot to learn.

Any assistance will be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: The windows partitions are mostly not auto mounted. Mount them first by following the steps in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open a file browser (called Nautilus) by clicking on the folder icon in the Unity Launcher (the vertical bar on the left of your screen). The icon should look like a folder with a darker house printed on it.

A Nautilus window opens up. In the left column you should find your windows partition. It should be called "OSDisk" or something like that. Click on the link and you will be able to browse the files of your windows installation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't see Nautilus so I opened Ubuntu Software Centre and typed 'Nautilus'. Apparently it is already installed, but I can't find it. Any suggestions on how else I can open Nautilus? Perhaps with the Terminal window?

Comment: In your terminal, just enter the command "nautilus".

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and was met with a message about having no /root/.config/nautilus. So in the terminal window I typed mkdir /root/.config/nautilus  Initially it appeared nothing had changed. After a few moments I noticed 'Devices' had appeared (I guess in nautilus?), and from there I could access my computer and all the windows files. So, many thanks! Your answer worked :)

Comment: You are welcome. Beware though that you should not get that kind of error (the `/root/.config` thing). It looks like you are running as root user by default, which is not acceptable from a safety point of view. Didn't you create a separate user during the installation ?

Comment: Oh, and then two minutes later 'Devices' has disappeared from nautilus, and I can no longer access my windows files...? As far as I know, I'm the only user.

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `whoami` ? What is the ouptut ?

Comment: It seems to be working. If I simply open the terminal window and type: nautilus         There is still no icon on the vertical bar on the left of the screen with a darker house on it. But, thanks again!